# Architecture Question

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, multilabel-classification

I have a situation where I need to propose a solution along with stack of technologies that need to be used for the below business case

Business Case:
I am receiving a car manufacturing data set from various car manufacturing companies, the data set for each car model is different and have different number of attributes but I do receive them in csv files every 2 minutes. I need to choose a particular storage format so that it is easy to query by each car model and based on the model, i select, i should be able to display the different features of that car model. Is there a recommended architecture for this type of data analysis?

Comment: Are you familiar with pandas library in python?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? For example: Is the data accumulated or will you replace old data with new? How much data are we talking about coming in every 2 minutes and how much data will be accumulated (it will grow quickly with this rate)? Is it a single record coming in or multiple records? Do they change over time or do you have a limited variety of models?

Comment: Hi Gegewind: The data is accumulated & i receive about 4500 files every 2 minutes and each file has about 75K records. Yes, they change over time and yes its a limited variety of models.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the data model you receive is different, it makes best sense for you to use a NoSql store like mongodb.

Here is the tech stack I would use ( python ) :

1. To receive requests with csv file, I would use flask microweb framework.
2. I would run flask with gunicorn and gevent.
3. For every csv file received, I would parse the rows based on varied columns and store them in a mongodb.
4. I would write queries on the collection in mongodb to extract information.

I would be more than happy to elaborate more if required .

Comment: Thanks Nischal. May i know if it is good to use spark for parsing python itself? If yes, may I know the reason? My question is indirectly what steps typically should make use of spark and what steps typically make use of python and why?

Comment: @NK7983 - Spark usecase is very different and it definitely does not fall in your current problem scope. SPARK has to do a lot of in memory processing which you do not require.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cloud Solution Steps-

1. Dump those files in S3
2. Initiate lambda function (serverless) for pre-processing data according to your need
3. Store this data into Redshift. 
   You can create generalized schema to store car details.